# Any way to use pandorabots node module with Nativescript?

Tags: node.js, npm, nativescript, node-modules

They have a [Pandorabots API module for Node.js](https://github.com/pandorabots/pb-node). After installing it and runnig the app I get Could not find module 'fs'. Thank you for any insight.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for asking

I have studied whole pandorabots docs but did not get any error like you are getting and my given code can only solve the problem for "fs"

if you are interested then, you can use that

```
$ npm install fs --save 

var fs =require('fs');
```